# Weird Eclipse/workspace behavior with Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

A couple weeks ago I installed Ubuntu side by side with windows. I recently installed Eclipse on Ubuntu, and wasn't really thinking and when Eclipse asked for a workspace, I just browsed to the Window's Eclipse workspace and used that one(probably a bad idea). I opened up a project changed a few minor code in Ubuntu Eclipse and then saved. I just tried to open the workspace in Window's Eclipse and nothing is showing up, none of the projects or anything at all. I can still browse to the files and they exist haven't been deleted. Any idea about what or why this happened?

Comment: Maybe newline issues in configuration files (can't imagine, but who knows)?

Comment: Thank you, yes this worked. I was wondering if it was a platform issue, or if it is because I was using Eclipse juno, and the eclipse I installed on Ubuntu from the Software center was 3.2 and not Juno. Thanks again, nice to have my projects back.

Comment: @themiDdlest I'll post as an answer, just for completeness.

Comment: Always is better to use git or similar. Or importing-exporting projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate workspace only for the windows eclipse, re-import the projects from the current workspace that is broken on windows to the new windows-only workspace. I can't entirely explain why but I've experienced this as well and this is the solution. Workspaces, for whatever reason, are not cross platform.